# Is there an alternative to Dean title?

Tags: university, titles, job

Because of different backgrounds in higher education systems, different titles are popularly used for administrative titles in academia such as

> University level - President, Vice Chancellor, Rector, Principal
>
> Faculty level - Dean only
>
> Department level - Head, Chair

For leading a faculty, the only common term is `Dean`. Am I right? or there are other alternatives too?

And more interestingly, the title of `Dean` is only used for the manager of a faculty, not other positions. Correct me if I'm wrong.

What is the historical meaning of `dean`, and what is special about this title, which is only used for a specific level in academia.

Comment: I think Oxford has "Chair of the Faculty" rather than Dean

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The title "Dean" is by no means restricted to the leader of a faculty (or college, or other similar unit). For instance, most US universities have a "Dean of Students" who is responsible for student services, discipline, etc. Some have a "Dean of Residential Life" who runs the dorms. My alma mater had a "Dean of Student Activities", popularly known as the "Dean of Fun".

Comment: "Dean of Fun"? Anything like the "Fun Police"? ;-)

Comment: @long: A little bit. His job was mostly to come up with things for students to do that didn't involve alcohol.  Concerts, subsidized movie tickets, and  so forth. It was kind of a losing battle but he tried valiantly.

Comment: @NateEldredge this is not what I meant. In some sense, `Dean of Students` is at the level of `Dean of Faculty` (both report to VP). I meant why the term of Dean is not used for other academic leaders; such as Dean of Department, Dean of Institute, Dean of Lab, Dean of Research Center or generally using the title of `Dean` instead of `Director`, which is very common for a wide range of leading positions?